# Event handler optimization

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just wondering if there is a way to refactore this code:

```
Template.bookmarks.events({
    // save changes
    'keyup .set_tag' : function(e,t) {
      if(e.which === 13) {
        save_changes(e.target.id.substring(3));
      }
    },

    'keyup .set_name' : function(e,t) {
      if(e.which === 13) {
        save_changes(e.target.id.substring(4));
      }
    },
    'click .save_changes' : function(e,t) {
      save_changes(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping in a form tag and listen to that form's submit event. Make sure to event.preventDefault()

You can then avoid all the keycode 13 stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
function action(key, offset) {
  return function(e, t) {
    if (e.which === key) {
      save_changes(e.target.id.substring(offset))
    }
  }
}

Template.bookmarks.events({
  // save changes
  'keyup .set_tag': action(13, 3),
  'keyup .set_name': action(13, 4),
  'click .save_changes': function(e, t) {
    save_changes(e.target.id);
  }
});
```

One way to solve it. I wouldn't try to force the third event handler into the `action` function as it would make the `action` function more complicated.